# Geometry of point blocked by a sphere

Tags: geometry, 3d, spherical-coordinates

Suppose there is a point located at $O = (0, 0, 0)$, and a sphere of radius $r$ at a distance $R$ from the point $O$. The sphere is located in the $x-y$ plane and orbits in $x-y$ plane in a circular radius $R$ about the point $O$. For an observer located at $(D, 0, 0)$, where $D\gg R, r$, I am interested in what fraction of the orbit is the point $O$ blocked by the sphere. In this case, it would just be $r/(2R)$.

Now, suppose the radius of sphere is not a constant, but changes over the orbit, such that $r = r(\phi)$, a function of phase $\phi$. Here, $\phi=0$ when the sphere is at position $(R, 0, 0)$ and $\phi =\pi$ when it is at the position $(-R, 0, 0)$, and $\phi\in [0, 2\pi)$. As an example, suppose $r= r_0(1+\cos(\phi))$. In this case, what would be the fraction of orbit that the point $O$ would be blocked by the  sphere to the observer?

Comment: "Blocked" = not visible by the observer ?

Comment: @JeanMarie yes "Blocked" = not visible by the observer

Comment: Just out of passerby curiosity, when $r$ is constant, is the fraction of orbit blocked $r/(2R)$, or $r/(\pi R)$? It looks to me that there's an arc of length $\approx 2r$ (for the center of the orbiting body along the orbit) where $O$ is blocked, while the orbit has length $2\pi R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in fact a 2D issue that can be followed on the following figure:

[image]

The ordinate of the center of the sphere is $R \sin(\varphi)$.

The ordinates of the projections of the endpoints of diameter of the sphere onto the $y$ axis are :

$$R \sin(\varphi)+r(\varphi) \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ R \sin(\varphi)-r(\varphi)$$

Occultation of the origin will take place iff these ordinates have opposite signs ; said otherwise, iff their product is negative.

Therefore, the fractional time of occultation is the integral of characteristic function (with value $1$ when true, $0$ otherwise) of :

$$R^2 \sin(\varphi)^2-r(\varphi)^2$$

divided by the total length $2 \pi R$, which can be given the following closed form:

$$\dfrac{1}{2 \pi R}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} H(r(\varphi)^2-R^2 \sin(\varphi)^2)d \varphi$$

where $H$ is [Heaviside function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

**Remark:** in the case where $r(\varphi)=r$ (a constant), one has the limit case

$$\sin(\varphi)=\tfrac{r}{R} \ \ \iff \ \  \varphi=\operatorname{asin}(\tfrac{r}{R})$$ giving the following formula for the fractional time of occupation :

$$\dfrac{1}{2\pi}2\operatorname{asin}(\tfrac{r}{R})=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\operatorname{asin}(\tfrac{r}{R})$$

Comment: How do I reconcile this with the fact that the for $r(\phi) = {\rm const}$, the fractional time of occultation is $r/(2R)$? The integral does not seem to suggest that.

Comment: I have discovered that the range of the integral I gave $(0,2 \pi)$ is not the right one. I have corrected it into $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$. I will answer you in a longer way in the coming hours.

Comment: The fractional time of occultation looks to be expressible under the closed form formula $\dfrac{\operatorname{asin}(r/R)}{π}$ which, for small values of $r/R$, can be assimilated to $\dfrac{r}{πR}$ (as noticed by @Andrew D. Hwang) but I do not find back your  $\dfrac{r}{2R}$. I will write down the proof.